# Use REGEX to generate multiple conversions per session in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've got a client with a real estate Website. Based on comparing goal completions to unique page views, it's pretty clear that some visitors inquire about multiple properties during a single session (more unique pages matching the REGEX string than completed goals). As goal tracking is set-up now, only one conversion per session is being completed (which I know is standard for GA).

I am using the destination as the confirmation of goal completion.

"Thank you" pages for conversions look like this:

/Enquiry/Thank-You/?subject=B30794&market=sale
/Enquiry/Thank-You/?subject=B36930&market=rental

My goal tracking REGEX is \Q/Enquiry/Thank-You/\E

I'm pretty sure that I can get Google Analytics to count more than one "thank you" as a completed goal during a session *if* I can account for the variable in the middle (B30794, B36930, etc.) plus the sale or rental on the end of the URL

I've asked around, including Google's GA community but can't get an string that works to handle the variable in the middle. These are two tags recommended to me that have not worked:

This string returns zero results:
^/Enquiry/Thank-You/\?subject=.*&market=(sale|rental)$

This string returns more than simply the thank you URLs:

^/Enquiry/Thank-You/\?subject=.*&market=sale|rental$

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, the issue for the empty one was that the characters were not escaped:

```
^\/Enquiry\/Thank\-You\/\?subject=.*&market=(sale|rental)$
```